# Methods for multivariate polynomial equations over large finite fields

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, groebner-bases, resultants

I am trying to get a rough overview of the best methods one might use to find solutions of multivariate polynomial equations over large finite fields. We can suppose for simplicity that the given system has a finite number of solutions (over the closure).

As I understand it, the general algebraic methods for finding solutions over *rational* numbers are either based on the Gröbner basis (computing the elimination ideal) or are based on the resultants.

**First question**: Are there any other general algebraic methods?

**Second (main) question**: Is the situation over finite fields any different? Are there any other general methods which only work for finite fields?

To maybe illustrate my confusion from all the sources I have been going through:
The figure on page 3 of this [thesis on finite field multivariate polynomial equations](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01110887/document) is trying to give the reader some rough overview. But it doesn't include any resultant-based methods. Are these not suitable for finite fields for some reason I am not seeing?

Any answers or sources to answers would be very appreciated.

Comment: There is no method easier than the Groebner basis method.

Comment: @dodd: That is not true. It depends on the specifics of the problem at hand. Sometimes Groebner bases work better and sometimes resultants work better. If one works over $\mathbb{C}$, and one is trying to find solutions by any means necessary, then there is also approximation methods, homotopy methods etc.

Comment: For the Groebner vs resultant competition, see for example A. Bressler, T. Greenwood, R. Pemantle and M. Petkovsek, "Quantum random walk on the integer lattice: Examples and phenomena", in Algorithmic Probability and Combinatorics,
eds. M. E. Lladser et al. (American Mathematical Society, Providence,
2010), pp. 41–60....

Comment: ...as well as B. Sturmfels, "Introduction to resultants", in Applications of Computational Algebraic Geometry, eds. D. A. Cox and B. Sturmfels (American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1998), pp. 25–39.